# Check if values of two columns are in a list of couples of values : pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, multiple-columns, contains, isin

I have a list of couples of values, and DataFrame.

- I want to create a new DataFrame d2 containing the rows of existing DataFrame d1 where values of columns `['A','B']` must be equal (both `A` and `B` at the same time) to at least one of couples in a list `c` of values.

Every tuto I see check if values in a DataFrame match a fixed one-or-two-pair of values at max.

For example :

```
c = [[1, 100], [2,200], [3, 300], ..., [5,500]]
dfa = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], "B": [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]})
```

At the moment, I did :

```
dfa[dfa[['A', 'B']].isin(c).all(axis=1)]
```

But it returns nothing, whereas it should return two rows !
I appreciate any help :)

Comment: `.all` is not for check "*at least one of couples*"

Comment: No, indeed `.all` checks that both `A` and `B` are equal to the requested values. But it does not work (`.any()` would check that wor `A` or `B` is equal to a requested value). I want any rows that match A and B at the same time.

Comment: Please read; [mre] Then edit your question to include desired results.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
dfa["new_col"] = dfa.values.tolist() #Column (A,B) values into a list in a new column
out = dfa[dfa["new_col"].isin(c)]
```